# No result displayed in GuidedTour.playground

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using the latest xCode 6 beta 6 and cannot see any result on the right column of GuidedTour.playground. Is anyone having this problem? I tried pressing "Execute Playground"  button and nothing happens either.  See picture below.

[image: GuidedTour Playground]

Comment: Does turning on "line wrapping" help?

Comment: Nope, I had tried toggling the line wrapping under XCode->Preferences->Text Editing->Indentation->Line Wrapping but it doesn't make any differences. Restarted XCode and Restarted macbook as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I figured maybe it was due to errors in the code of the guided tour playground. Scroll down to see code with errors.

I commented all the lines of code with a red "!" at the left of them and now it works fine, I have the computed code displayed at right of the window.